# Generating Java Source from an XSD that defines SOAP messages

Tags: java, soap, xsd

I have an XSD that defines the SOAP messages for a remote device. I want to take this XSD and generate from it Java source code to create these messages. An example of one message in the XSD is this:

```
<xs:element name="get-ethernet-stats">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>Ethernet stats information</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="mode" type="response-mode"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="get-ethernet-stats-resp">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Ethernet Stats</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="status"/>
            <xs:element name="result" minOccurs="0">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="rx" type="xs:int"/>
                        <xs:element name="tx" type="xs:int"/>
                        <xs:element name="drops" type="xs:int"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Any suggestions on how to do this? I have looked into JAXB but I don't have the original source files, and when I run "xjc file.xsd" to get the source files, here is part of the output:

```
parsing a schema...
compiling a schema...
[ERROR] A class/interface with the same name "file.MemosReceipt" is already in use. Use a class customization to resolve this conflict.
  line 7669 of file:/Users/rwb7041/Documents/file/xsd/file.xsd.xsd

[ERROR] (Relevant to above error) another "MemosReceipt" is generated from here.
  line 8242 of file:/Users/rwb7041/Documents/file/xsd/file.xsd.xsd

[ERROR] A class/interface with the same name "file.InstructionsReceipt" is already in use. Use a class customization to resolve this conflict.
  line 7720 of file:/Users/rwb7041/Documents/file/xsd/file.xsd.xsd

[ERROR] (Relevant to above error) another "InstructionsReceipt" is generated from here.
  line 8341 of file:/Users/rwb7041/Documents/file/xsd/file.xsd.xsd

[ERROR] Two declarations cause a collision in the ObjectFactory class.
  line 7686 of file:/Users/rwb7041/Documents/file/xsd/file.xsd.xsd

[ERROR] (Related to above error) This is the other declaration.   
  line 8267 of file:/Users/rwb7041/Documents/file/xsd/file.xsd.xsd

[ERROR] Two declarations cause a collision in the ObjectFactory class.
  line 8626 of file:/Users/rwb7041/Documents/file/xsd/file.xsd.xsd

[ERROR] (Related to above error) This is the other declaration.   
  line 6114 of file:/Users/rwb7041/Documents/file/xsd/file.xsd.xsd

Failed to produce code.
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you have a look at [jaxws-rt-2.1.4.jar](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2/com/sun/xml/ws/jaxws-rt/2.1.4/jaxws-rt-2.1.4.jar). This allows for two ways of supplying the XML to be sent in the SOAP message:
(1) supply just the body contents; the code takes care of adding Envelope/Header/Body plus namespaces according to the wsdl retrieved
(2) supply the complete Envelope, plus namespaces

No code generation is required then.

See for instance  [jaxws-guide.html](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/jaxws-guide.html)

Comment: I don't exactly see how this helps. I understand that it will help me generate the SOAP envelope, but based on my understanding, I will have to generate the body. In order to generate the body, I have to know what message to send and to do that I need to generate the appropriate classes from the XSD to hold the contents of the body

Comment: Well, not sure then exactly what you are looking for, but the way I use it is create a new DOM document, fill it according to the XSD specs and specific details (code generation may help here but why bother), then string the DOM into XML and pass it to a new instance of `javax.xml.ws.Service`, supplying port, service, XML and WSDL url to the `createDispatch` method.

Comment: I dont have a WSDL document, so this does not help at all

Comment: Normally, the webservice itself will provide you with the WSDL. Its url is more or less the webservice url + `.asmx?wsdl`. For example `https://www.eway.com.au/gateway/rebill/test/manageRebill_test.asmx?wsdl`.

Comment: it is not a web service, it is a remote device that I am trying to control. There is no WSDL